# Console symbol for "returned value"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, undefined

I'm using Chrome's Javascript console. Sometimes I see `undefined` preceded with a special symbol (I showed it as * in the example below, but it actually looks like a tiny arrow pointing to the left). Sometimes `undefined` is not preceded by anything. Why is that?

```
> var number = 5;
undefined
> console.log("something")
something
*undefined
```

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it is. Thanks! Couldn't think of a name for the symbol, so my search didn't yield any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just intended to distinguish console output from the value returned by the expression. It's apparently only used when an expression causes console output, since that's when the distinction is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. It seems crazy that this symbol wouldn't be used in all cases. It's much more confusing when it's used only in some cases.

Comment: As I said, it's only used when `console.log()` was used to print something in the console. I have no idea if there's a name for the character. It looks kind of like an eye looking at the result.